# Javascript Filter is not working after update Bootstrap and JQUERY Versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, bootstrap-5

I have a generic filter working that filters a data in a datatable.

When I upgrade my versions of bootstrap and jquery completely stop working.

- New Version of Bootstrap: bootstrap-5.2.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
- New Version of JQuery: jquery-3.6.1.min.js

Anyone has any idea ?
Any idea how to start ?

```
(function($) {

    $.enhanceUI(function(parent, findAndTouch) {

        var SELECTED_ICON = "icon-ok";
        var UNSELECTED_ICON = "icon-remove";
        findAndTouch("AjaxFilter", '[data-ajaxfilter]').each(function() {
            var impl = $(this);
            var uiOptions = impl.data("ajaxfilter");
            if (uiOptions == null || !$.isPlainObject(uiOptions) || uiOptions.column == null) {
                $.log("Wrong ajaxfilter options.", impl);
                return;
            }
            var input = impl.find("input");
            var parent = impl.parents(".ajaxfilter-parent:first");
            var select = parent.find("select");
            var inputName = select.attr('name');
            var loadOptionsButton = parent.find("[name~=loadOptions]");
            var button = impl.find("button");
            var counter = parent.find(".filter-value-count");
            var menu = parent.find(".dropdown-menu").css({
                left : "auto",
                top : "auto",
                minWidth : input.parent().width(),
                maxHeight : "400px",
                overflowX : "hidden",
                overflowY : "auto"
            });
            menu.hide();
            var itemLoading = $("<li/>").addClass("ajaxfilter-loading").text("Loading...").appendTo(menu);
            var itemSelectedDivider = $("<li/>").addClass("divider").hide().appendTo(menu);
            var itemNone = $("<li/>").hide().addClass("disabled");
            itemNone.append($("<a/>").text("- none -").attr("href", "#").attr("tabindex", -1));
            itemNone.appendTo(menu);

            button.click(function() {
                startQuery();
                updateMenu();
                if (!button.hasClass("open")) {
                    showMenu();
                } else {
                    hideMenu();
                }
            });
            input.focus(function() {
                startQuery();
            });
            input.keydown(function(e) {
                //$.log("keydown ", e.keyCode);
                if (e.keyCode == 13 /* ENTER */) {
                    var key = menu.find(".ajaxfilter-option.active:visible a").data("optionKey");
                    if (key != null) {
                        toggleOption(key);
                    }
                } else if (e.keyCode == 40 /* DOWN */) {
                    showMenu();
                    changeHighlighted(1);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 38 /* UP */) {
                    showMenu();
                    changeHighlighted(-1);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 9 /* TAB */) {
                    //Do not call startUpdateMenu
                    return;
                } else {
                    startUpdateMenu(true); //Delayed to retrieve the new value and show if needed
                    return;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });

            parent.on("blur", "*", startHideMenu);
            parent.on("focus", "*", cancelHideMenu);

            parent.on("click", ".ajaxfilter-option a", function(e) {
                //$.log("option clicked.", this);
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                toggleOption($(this).data("optionKey"));
                return false;
            });

            impl.show();
            select.hide();
            loadOptionsButton.hide();

            var options = null;
            var query = null;

            function showMenu() {
                cancelHideMenu();
                if (!button.hasClass("open")) {
                    button.addClass("open");
                    menu.show();
                }
            }

            function startQuery() {
                if (options == null && query == null) {
                    query = $.managedAjax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : window.location,
                        global : false,
                        data : {
                            action : "dv loadOptions " + uiOptions.column,
                            type : 'getOptions',
                            column : uiOptions.column,
                            fragments : "dataViewFilter"
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            try {
                                $.log("Options fetched " + uiOptions.column, data);
                                //alert(data.ee);
                                var dom = $.buildDOM(data.fragments.dataViewFilter);
                                var optionElements = dom.find(".dv-filter-" + uiOptions.column);
                                optionElements = optionElements.find("optgroup, option");
                                var newOptions = {};
                                $.each(optionElements, function() {
                                    var domElement = $(this);
                                    if (domElement.is("option")) {
                                        var key = $.trim(domElement.val());
                                        if (key.length == 0) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        var title = domElement.attr("title");
                                        if (title == null || title.length == 0) {
                                            title = domElement.text();
                                        }
                                        var label = domElement.text();
                                        var option = {
                                            key : key,
                                            label : {
                                                item : label,
                                                selectedItem : title
                                            }
                                        };
                                        ensureOptionItem(option, "item").hide().appendTo(menu);
                                        newOptions[key] = option;
                                    } else if (domElement.is("optgroup")) {
                                        var label = domElement.attr("label");
                                        var item = $("<li/>");
                                        if (label == null || label.length == 0) {
                                            item.addClass("divider");
                                        } else {
                                            item.text(label);
                                            item.addClass("divider-label");
                                        }
                                        item.appendTo(menu);
                                    }
                                });
                                options = newOptions;
                                //Load selected values
                                select.find("option:selected").each(function() {
                                    toggleOption($(this).attr('value'));
                                });
                                select.attr('name', '');
                                updateCounter();
                                query = null;
                                //$.log("Options processed " + uiOptions.column, options);
                                updateMenu();
                            } catch (ex) {
                                $.log("Exception during success of options query", ex);
                            }
                        },
                        afterUnmanagedError : function(request) {
                            alert("An error occured.");
                            hideMenu();
                            query = null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            var startUpdateMenuTimeout = null;
            function startUpdateMenu(doShow) {
                if (startUpdateMenuTimeout != null) {
                    clearTimeout(startUpdateMenuTimeout);
                    startUpdateMenuTimeout = null;
                }
                startUpdateMenuTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    updateMenu(doShow);
                }, 100);
            }
            function updateMenu(doShow) {
                changeHighlighted(null);
                var term = input.val();
                if (term != null) {
                    term = $.trim(term);
                }
                if (options == null) {
                    itemLoading.show();
                } else {
                    itemLoading.hide();
                    var matcher = null;
                    if (term != null && term.length > 0) {
                        matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
                    }
                    var countAll = 0;
                    var countSelected = 0;
                    var countVisible = 0;
                    var countSelectedOrMatching = 0;
                    $.each(options, function(key, option) {
                        countAll++;
                        var matching = matcher == null //
                                || matcher.test(option.label.item) //
                                || matcher.test(option.label.selectedItem);
                        var visible = matching;
                        if (option.selected) {
                            visible = false;
                            countSelected++;
                            var item = ensureOptionItem(option, "selectedItem");
                            item.toggleClass("ajaxfilter-matching", matcher != null && matching);
                            itemSelectedDivider.before(item);
                            item.show();
                        } else if (option.selectedItem != null) {
                            option.selectedItem.hide();
                        }
                        if (option.selected || matching) {
                            countSelectedOrMatching++;
                        }
                        if (visible) {
                            countVisible++;
                        }
                        option.item.toggle(visible);
                        option.item.toggleClass("ajaxfilter-matching", matcher != null && matching);
                    });
                    var noneVisible = countAll == 0;
                    noneVisible = noneVisible || (countVisible == 0 && (countSelected != countAll));
                    itemNone.toggle(noneVisible);
                    itemSelectedDivider.toggle((noneVisible || countVisible > 0) && (countSelected > 0));
                }
                if (doShow && term != null && term.length >= 3) {
                    showMenu();
                }
            }

            function changeHighlighted(diff) {
                var items = menu.find(".ajaxfilter-option:visible");
                var active = items.filter(".active");
                active = active.get(0);
                var index = $.inArray(active, items);
                menu.find(".ajaxfilter-option").removeClass("active");
                if (diff != null && items.length > 0) {
                    index += diff;
                    if (index < 0) {
                        index = items.length - 1;
                    }
                    if (index >= items.length) {
                        index = 0;
                    }
                    $(items.get(index)).addClass("active");
                }
            }

            function ensureOptionItem(option, optionProperty) {
                var out = option[optionProperty];
                if (out == null) {
                    var link = $("<a/>").attr("href", "#" + option.key);
                    link.text(" " + option.label[optionProperty]);
                    link.attr("tabindex", -1);
                    var icon = $("<span/>").addClass("icon- " + (option.selected ? SELECTED_ICON : UNSELECTED_ICON));
                    link.prepend(icon);
                    link.data("optionKey", option.key);
                    out = $("<li/>").addClass("ajaxfilter-option option-" + optionProperty).append(link);
                    option[optionProperty] = out;
                }
                return out;
            }
            function toggleOption(optionKey) {
                var option = options[optionKey];
                if (option == null) {
                    return;
                }
                option.selected = !option.selected;
                var items = $().add(option.item).add(option.selectedItem);
                if (option.selected) {
                    items.find(".icon-").addClass(SELECTED_ICON).removeClass(UNSELECTED_ICON);
                    parent.append(ensureInput(option));
                } else {
                    items.find(".icon-").addClass(UNSELECTED_ICON).removeClass(SELECTED_ICON);
                    ensureInput(option).remove();
                }
                updateCounter();
            }
            function updateCounter() {
                var count = 0;
                $.each(options, function(key, option) {
                    if (option.selected) {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
                counter.text(count > 0 ? count : "");
            }
            function ensureInput(option) {
                if (option.input == null) {
                    var input = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden");
                    input.attr("name", inputName).val(option.key);
                    option.input = input;
                }
                return option.input;
            }

            function hideMenu() {
                button.removeClass("open");
                menu.hide();
            }

            var startHideMenuTimeout = null;
            function cancelHideMenu() {
                if (startHideMenuTimeout != null) {
                    clearTimeout(startHideMenuTimeout);
                    startHideMenuTimeout = null;
                }
            }
            function startHideMenu() {
                cancelHideMenu();
                startHideMenuTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    var focused = parent.find(":focus");
                    if (focused.length == 0) {
                        hideMenu();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }

        });

        findAndTouch("QuickFilter", '.dv-filters form').each(function() {
            var form = $(this);
            var input = form.parents('.dv-filters:first').find('.dv-quick-filter input');
            if (input.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            var items = [];
            form.find("select").each(function() {
                var select = $(this);
                var category = select.parent().find("h5").text();
                select.find("option").each(function() {
                    var option = $(this);
                    var item = {};
                    item.select = select;
                    item.option = option;
                    item.category = category;
                    item.text = option.text();
                    if (item.text == "All") {
                        return;
                    }
                    var title = option.attr('title');
                    if (title) {
                        item.text = title;
                    } else {
                        var grp = option.parent("optgroup").attr("label");
                        if (grp) {
                            item.text = grp + ": " + item.text;
                        }
                    }
                    item.label = category + " - " + item.text;
                    items.push(item);
                });
            });
            intput.unbind() //
            //.attr('type', 'text') //
            .css('width', '300px') //
            .autocomplete({
                delay : 0,
                source : function(request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    var filteredItems = $.grep(items, function(item) {
                        return matcher.test(item.label);
                    });
                    if (filteredItems.length > 10) {
                        filteredItems.length = 10;
                    }
                    response(filteredItems);
                },
                focus : function(event, ui) {
                    return false;
                },
                select : function(event, ui) {
                    //Clear form selection
                    var selectInputs = form.find("select");
                    selectInputs.find("option:selected").prop('selected', false);
                    //Set selection
                    ui.item.option.prop('selected', true);
                    selectInputs.trigger('change');
                    form.find("button[name~=action][name~=filter]").trigger('click');
                    return false;
                }
            }) //
            .focus();

        });

        var selector = '.workOnBehalf, .declineTask,.signTask, .approveTask, .disapproveTask, ' 
                + '.rerunTask, .cancelTask, .reopenTask, .reassignTask, ' //
                + '.exportFinalESR, .exportMergeIER, .exportPrint, .showAsFlow';

        findAndTouch("FlowDialog", selector).each(function() {
            var source = $(this);
            var options = {
                additionalCloseSelector : '[name~="cancel"]',
                width : "350px",
                position : [ "center", 100 ]
            };
            if (source.is(".declineTask")) {
                options.width = "550px";
            } else if (source.is(".reassignTask")) {
                options.width = "900px";
            } else if (source.is(".showAsFlow")) {
                options.witdh = "500px";
            }
            source.flowDialog(options);
        });
    });

    $(function() { // DOM Ready
        if($('#myModal').length > 0){
            $("#myModal").modal('show'); 
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            }, 6000);
            var uri = window.location.toString();
            if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
                var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
                window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
            }
        }
    }); // End DOM Ready

})(jQuery);
```

Is there a way to start validating this?

Comment: can you share some error messages ? Probably you find those in the browser console

Comment: That's a big code dump (several hundred lines of code), with probably the most relevant parts buried in there somewhere, or maybe even completely missing from your question. There is no information about any error messages - just "_completely stop working_". So, where I would start: (1) Take a look at how to provide a [mre]. Start with _no code at all_ and add _only_ the code needed to recreate your specific problem. Show us that, with some suitable data. (2) Show us the libraries you are using with their versions.

Comment: (3) Use the DataTables [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) to make sure you have a compatible set of libraries (jQuery/DataTables/Bootstrap/etc.). That is where I would start.

Comment: Are you even using DataTables? You tagged this as a DataTables question. But if you are not actually using that product, you should remove that tag from your question. Hover your mouse over each tag to read a summary about the tag.